# how to find decode way to decode a USSD Command's result in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, gsm, decoding, modem, ussd

I'm working on my GSM modem (Huawei E171) to send USSD commands.
to do this i use this commands at the first:

```
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CSCS=?  ----> result is "IRA" this is my modem default
```

after that i sent these commands and i have got these results and everything works fine.

//*141*1# ----->to check my balance

```
+CUSD: 
   0,"457A591C96EB40B41A8D0692A6C36C17688A2E9FCB667AD87D4EEB4130103D
      0C8281E4753D0B1926E7CB2018881E06C140F2BADE5583819A4250D24D2FC
      BDD653A485AD787DD65504C068381A8EF76D80D2287E53A55AD5653D554
      31956D04",15
```

//*100# ---->  this command give me some options to charge my mobile

```
+CUSD: 
    1,"06280627062C06470020062706CC06310627064606330644000A0030002E062E0
       63106CC062F00200634062706310698000A0031002E067E062706330627063106A
       F0627062F000A0032002E0622067E000A0033002E06450644062A000A003
       4002E06330627064506270646000A0035002E067E0627063106330
       6CC06270646000A002300200028006E0065007800740029000A",72
```

i found some codes to decode these result:

to decode checking balance result i used:

```
        string result141="457A591C96EB40B41A8D0692A6C36C17688A......."
        byte[] packedBytes = ConvertHexToBytes(result141);
        byte[] unpackedBytes = UnpackBytes(packedBytes);

        //gahi in kar mikone gahi balkaee nafahmidam chera
        string o = Encoding.Default.GetString(unpackedBytes);
```

my function's codes are:

```
   public static byte[] ConvertHexToBytes(string hexString)
    {
           if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
               return null;

          int len = hexString.Length / 2;
          byte[] array = new byte[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            string tmp = hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2);
            array[i] = 
            byte.Parse(tmp, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }

        return array;
    }


   public static byte[] UnpackBytes(byte[] packedBytes)
    {
        byte[] shiftedBytes = new byte[(packedBytes.Length * 8) / 7];

        int shiftOffset = 0;
        int shiftIndex = 0;

        // Shift the packed bytes to the left according 
        //to the offset (position of the byte)
        foreach (byte b in packedBytes)
        {
            if (shiftOffset == 7)
            {
                shiftedBytes[shiftIndex] = 0;
                shiftOffset = 0;
                shiftIndex++;
            }

            shiftedBytes[shiftIndex] = (byte)((b << shiftOffset) & 127);

            shiftOffset++;
            shiftIndex++;
        }

        int moveOffset = 0;
        int moveIndex = 0;
        int unpackIndex = 1;
        byte[] unpackedBytes = new byte[shiftedBytes.Length];

        // 
        if (shiftedBytes.Length > 0)
        {
            unpackedBytes[unpackIndex - 1] = 
            shiftedBytes[unpackIndex - 1];
        }

        // Move the bits to the appropriate byte (unpack the bits)
        foreach (byte b in packedBytes)
        {
            if (unpackIndex != shiftedBytes.Length)
            {
                if (moveOffset == 7)
                {
                    moveOffset = 0;
                    unpackIndex++;
                    unpackedBytes[unpackIndex - 1] = 
                    shiftedBytes[unpackIndex - 1];
                }

                if (unpackIndex != shiftedBytes.Length)
                {
                    // Extract the bits to be moved
                    int extractedBitsByte = (packedBytes[moveIndex] &
                                            _decodeMask[moveOffset]);
                    // Shift the extracted bits to the proper offset
                    extractedBitsByte = 
                               (extractedBitsByte >> (7 - moveOffset));
                    // Move the bits to the appropriate byte 
                    //(unpack the bits)
                    int movedBitsByte = 
                      (extractedBitsByte | shiftedBytes[unpackIndex]);

                    unpackedBytes[unpackIndex] = (byte)movedBitsByte;

                    moveOffset++;
                    unpackIndex++;
                    moveIndex++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Remove the padding if exists
        if (unpackedBytes[unpackedBytes.Length - 1] == 0)
        {
            byte[] finalResultBytes = new byte[unpackedBytes.Length - 1];
            Array.Copy(unpackedBytes, 0, 
                       finalResultBytes, 0, finalResultBytes.Length);
            return finalResultBytes;
        }
        return unpackedBytes;
      }
```

but to decode second result i used:

```
string strHex= "06280627062C06470020062706CC06310......";

   strHex = strHex.Replace(" ", "");
          int nNumberChars = strHex.Length / 2;
          byte[] aBytes = new byte[nNumberChars];
          using (var sr = new StringReader(strHex))
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < nNumberChars; i++)
                aBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(
                            new String(new char[2] { 
                            (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
        }
   string decodedmessage= Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.
                        GetString(aBytes, 0, aBytes.Length);
```

---

both of theme works current but why i should different decoding way to decode these results?

from where i can find, i should use which one of these two types of decoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USSD command responses +CUSD unsolicited responses are formatted as follows:

```
+CUSD: <m>[<str_urc>[<dcs>]]
```

Where "m" is the type of action required, "str_urc" is the response string, and "dcs" is the response string encoding.

This quote is from a Siemens Cinterion MC55i manual but applies generally to other modem manufacturers:

> If dcs indicates that GSM 03.38 default alphabet is used TA converts GSM alphabet into current TE character
>   set according to rules of GSM 07.05 Annex A. Otherwise in case of invalid or omitted dcs conversion of
>   str_urc is not possible.

USSD's can be sent in 7-Bit encoded format or UC2 hence when looking at your two example responses you can see either a DCS of 15 or 72.

> GSM 03.38 Cell Broadcast Data Coding Scheme in integer format (default 15). In case of an invalid or omitted
>   dcs from the network side (MT)  will not be given out.

So if you get a DCS of 15 then it is 7-Bit encoded. And if it's 72 then it will be UC2. So from this you can easily select either your first decoding routine or second.

Comment: thanks for your nice answer but can you tel me please what is the relation between 15 and 7-Bit encode or 75 and UC2, i mean is that a formula or something to calculate 75 or 15 ?or these numbers are predefined?

Comment: Yes, there is coding scheme for the coding scheme :) Best bet is to take a read of the 3GPP 03.38 spec. Search for Cell Broadcast Data Coding Scheme. It's relatively simple that bits 3 and 2 determine the alphabet being used. For 7-Bit its Bit3 = 0 Bit2 = 0 and for UC2 its Bit3=1 Bit2 = 0. There are some nuances in comparison to SMS encoding. The details I can't 100% recall.